# Understanding Phone Service from Cable Companies

Tags: communication, telephone, network

Since communication technology is considered part of EE, I thought I would pose this question here - hopefully it is on-topic.

Cable companies like Comcast have been offering home phone service for some time now, and they claim their phone service has the "highest clarity".

Questions:
1. Is the phone service provided cable companies simply VOIP?
2. Since the voice signals are eventually routed to the PSTN, how can cable phone service surpass the quality of traditional phone service provided (by companies like AT&T) through the phone jack?

**In response to comment**
I believe the how and why's of engineering needs to be understood before an answer is formulated.

Comment: Learn about audio compression technology used by VoIP...

Comment: The PSTN these days is all digital.  But the "last mile" from the exchange to the phone is analog.  Replacing this with a high bit-rate VOIP service is likely to improve sound quality.